# Tiling by S-tetrominos and Z-tetrominos on a lattice polygon $P$

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

We call an S-tetromino and a Z-tetromino for shapes in the image below:

[image]

Now assume that a lattice polygon $P$ can be covered exclusively using S-tetrominos. Prove that if we also try to use Z-tetrominos in combination with S-tetrominos, or if not then exclusively, to cover the polygon $P$, then the number of Z-tetrominos must be even.

---

Attempt: I already know a solution using the method of colouring. But notice this pattern:

[image: 2 S-tetros] [image: 2 Z-tetros]

So if the exclusive S-tetros in $P$ includes the blue one, then we can also have 2 Z-tetros for each pattern. I have done brief experiment and it seems the polygon $P$ that can be tiled exclusively using S-tetros can be covered also with $Z$-tetros ***only when this pattern occurs*** (or the rotated version). Is this true?